# Qualtrics and Epi Info yield different Standard Deviation values?

Tags: standard-deviation, survey, epidemiology

Uncertain if this is the correct place to post this, but I'll give it a shot. I'm a Master's Student working with a small (n=25 respondents) data set. I originally entered my surveys into Qualtrics. Qualtrics gave me a Standard Deviation value of 1.33 for my variable. I imported my dataset into Epi Info, and used the Means analysis gadget on the exact same variable. The standard deviation is now 1.3557. why might this be?

Additional information that might(?) be important:

-This variable includes 2 missing values, which I used the Qualtrics -99 setting for. When I ran a line list in Epi Info to see if these were being counted differently, both came up as "missing" which is correct.

-The means from Epi Info and Qualtrics both match.

Comment: Maybe Qualtrics is using an uncorrected (biased) estimator of the variance? Note that $\sqrt{24/25}\cdot 1.3557\approx 1.33$. Maybe the documentation gives a hint which formula is used?

Comment: I appreciate your response! I will try to look into the documentation.

Comment: You were correct. I did the math by hand (as one ought) and figured out that Qualtrics used N =23 , Epi Info used N-1 = 22.